Headless mode while using Selenium webdriver won't perform function
This is a nested function inside a function that I defined. But somehow the webdriver in Headless mode just won't perform the xport.click function. This function WORKS on a regular window but won't in headless.
def xPort():
    wait = WebDriverWait(symbion, 450)
    xport = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ctl00_cplMain_ExportToExcel0")))
    xport.click()

I'm expecting the function to perform the click function after the element is clickable. It works on window mode but won't in headless.

Please provide  versions of selenium and your browsers

I'm currently using Selenium v. 4.19.0 and Chrome is Version 124.0.6367.79
